# Julia - can a global variable be used in a function before it is defined?

Tags: julia

At this top of this page https://julia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-tips under global variables, they use this example:

```
global x
y = f(x::Int + 1)
```

`x` can't be used in the function because it isn't defined. What exactly are they doing there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just short hand notation.  They are assuming that `x` gets defined elsewhere between its global declaration and the function call.  Note that the function `f()` is not defined in that tiny snippet from the docs either.